# Is there a method to display MySQL table values using PHP for each specific user to see their profile in a react native app?

Tags: react-native

[app user profile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zWz3C.jpg)`enter code here` **I am a React Native Newbie. I need to show name, phone, other attributes from MySQL table and using PHP, I need to display these data in my react native app's user profile page. I do not know how to display this.**

I need to get that thing in this block

```
<View style={styles.sectionStyle}>
  <Image source={require('../../Image/person-icon.png')} style={styles.imageStyle} />
  <TextInput style={styles.input} placeholder="Name" placeholderTextColor="black" editable={false}
    selectTextOnFocus={false} />
</View>
<View style={styles.sectionStyle}>
  <Image source={require('../../Image/phone-icon.png')} style={styles.imageStyle} />
  <TextInput style={styles.input} placeholder="Phone" placeholderTextColor="black" editable={false}
    selectTextOnFocus={false} />
</View>
</View>
```

Answer (score 0):

React Native is a mobile app, MySQL is database server, you cannot access tables directly from JS in RN app. You need create API, install and configure a local webserver (google will help you), then when you deploy it, inside your RN component you can try use fetch function:

```
    componentDidMount() {
        fetch(YOUR_API_URL)
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(data => this.setState({ name: data.name, name: data.name  }));
    }
```

or if you are using hooks:

```
  useEffect(() => {
   fetch(YOUR_API_URL)
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(data => {
            setName(data.name);
            setPhone(data.phone);
          }));
  }, [])
```

P.S. That is not a common task, you should learn more about webservers, protocols, and communication between your web application and mobile app. Good luck!

Comment: Let me learn as you said and thanks for suggesting me this method